# Strange Problem with AppleTV icon - icon shrinks when selected on 4K models?

Tags: tvos, apple-tv

In a basic AppleTV app.

ON 4K models.

When you roll over the icon, the iml becomes 1/2 size and sits top right, and the rest of the icon area is just gray.

Has anyone seen this behavior?

Same build works perfectly on pre-4K AppleTV models.

Have endlessly checked that all the image assets are correct. This on Xcode 13.4.

The actual parallax nonsense works perfectly - but with the icon sitting in the top quarter only of the icon area!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After hours, here's the solution which is totally undocumented.

The three (or two) 1x images:

- Should be 400.240 (in fact, causes no problems if size is wrong)

The three (or two) 2x images:

- **MUST be strictly 800.480** or will fail catastrophically and silently on 4K models

[image: xcode]

Depressingly, SOME of the images in the asset folder, include working and correct alerts, for example:

[image: alert]

However the actual "App Icon" slots DO NOT HAVE any working alerts.

Bottom line, MUST be exactly 800.480.

---

The "Top Shelf" images are:

1920.720 and 3840.1440

The "Top Shelf Wide" images are:

2320.720 and 4640.1440

Comment: Notice the alerts, in large yellow boxes, and red text.  Furthermore, the brand new appleTV models are here (November 2022), we have some but I have not fully tested these issues yet. Further, each time tvOS slightly updates, Apple fool with these issues.  So the answer is not simple at any given time, for the hardware models available.